# Aggregation Annotation Not Working It is Returning Empty

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, aggregation

I am trying to make this Aggregation bellow using Spring Java, but it's returning an **Empty List** on my console. This is working on MongoDB, but not on my spring application.

This is my MongoDB Query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        {
          user_id: "256f5280-fb49-4ad6-b7f5-65c4329d46e0"
        },
        {
          time: {
            $gte: 1622471890,
            $lt: 1822471890
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      time: -1
    }
  }
])
```

It's return me 2 results:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "message": "This is an example of my db (1)",
    "time": 1.62247189e+09,
    "user_id": "256f5280-fb49-4ad6-b7f5-65c4329d46e0"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
    "message": "This is an example of my db (2)",
    "time": 1.62247189e+09,
    "user_id": "256f5280-fb49-4ad6-b7f5-65c4329d46e0"
  }
]
```

My Problem is when I do this using Mongo with Spring Java:

**My Repository**

```
@Aggregation(pipeline = {
    "{" +
        "$match: {" +
          "$and: [" +
            "{" +
              "user_id: ?2" +
            "}," +
            "{" +
              "time: {" +
                "$gte: ?0," +
                "$lt: ?1" +
              "}" +
            "}" +
          "]" +
        "}" +
      "}",
      "{" +
        "$sort: {" +
          "time: -1" +
        "}" +
    "}"
})
List<MessagesUser> findByPeriodAndUserIdPaginated(long from, long to, String user_id, Pageable pageable);
```

**A part of My Service**

```
@Override
public Page<MessagesUser> findAllBetween(Date from, Date to, Pageable page, String user_id) {

    List<MessagesUser> messagesUserList = messagesUserRepository.findByPeriodAndUserIdPaginated(from.getTime() / 1000, to.getTime() / 1000, user_id, page);
    
    System.out.println("messagesUserList: ");
    System.out.println(messagesUserList); // It is the empty list
```

This Java Query Repository is returning to me an empty array instead of my 2 values. You should see the **Dataset** and an example working well on MongoDB Query here: [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fthIBgno_zi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After [Gibbs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72283097) I had an idea (to check if query was executing the correct variables) and I found the problem, but it was in my **@Document** collection name.

First I added Query Logs on my console application to see if it was working well, and It was!

To check logs I Added this line on my *application.properties*
`logging.level.org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate=DEBUG`

And I saw that Query was correct by log, but the collection name that the Query executing was incorrect, It was executing on **messagesUser** instead **messagesuser**, so I changed the collection name in my **Entity MessagesUser** and it worked.

**After (It solved and It's Working)**

```
@Document(collection="messagesuser")
public class MessagesUser{

    public MessagesUser(String user_id, Long time) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
        this.time = time;
    }
// [continuation of the entity code...]
```

**Before (It wasn't working)**

```
@Document
public class MessagesUser{

    public MessagesUser(String user_id, Long time) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
        this.time = time;
    }
// [continuation of the entity code...]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your annotation

You have used

`"user_id: ?2" +`

but `user_id` is a 4th param then you need to use

`"user_id: ?3" +`

Comment: It isn't the correct answer to my question, but you gave me an idea and this idea works!!! I will answer with the solution, thank you.

The ?2 is acutally ?2, because in my repository the user_id is present in 2nd params position.